# Use of undeclared error :Alert error in ViewController.m in an iOS Application

Tags: ios, ios6, ios-simulator

An error is getting while doing code in my Application and the task is to redirect to url after alert. but about the code what I guess is correct. And here is my code

```
- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title :(int)tag
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                       message:msg
                                                       delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    if (tag) alert.tag = tag;
    {
    [alertView show];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(alertView.tag == 101)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://ABC.company.com"]];
        //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

the error is showing at the line

```
if (tag) alert.tag = tag;(Use of undeclared identifier:alert)
```

Comment: Change alert to alertView

Comment: yes, you are correct. I forgotten that silly thing. abyway thank you so much.... -@akshay1188

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of ...errors (omissions)

- `- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg **withTitle**:(NSString *)title **andTag**:(int)tag`
- `if (tag) alert.tag = tag;` // but previously you declare `alertView`

Comment: that's not the main problem. but it is something need to be corrected.